# Nested state with the same name

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am implementing react with redux and I got a nested state with the same name (See picture)

[image]

Here is my reducer:

```
function helps(state = {
  isFetching: false,
  items: []
}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.HELPS_FEED_REQUEST:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: true
      });
    case types.HELPS_FEED_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        items: [
          ...state.items,
          ...action.items
        ]
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  helps
});

export default rootReducer;
```

the index.js reducer:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import help from './helpReducer';
import helps from './helpsReducer';


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    help,
    helps
});

export default rootReducer;
```

My question is: Why I don't have only one "helps" state with isFetching and items? Is there something obvious that I am missing?

**EDIT:**

Apparently, it is because of I am using combine reducer. So if I change the name of the function to, for example helps_feed, the state will be:

```
helps
-- helps_feed
```

Why does combineReducers make a nested state?

configureStore.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import createSagaMiddleware, {END} from 'redux-saga';
import helpSagas from '../sagas/helpSaga';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const rootSagas = [
    helpSagas
  ];
  const sagaMiddleWare = createSagaMiddleware();

  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleWare),
      window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
  ));

  store.runSaga = sagaMiddleWare.run(...rootSagas);
  store.close = () => store.dispatch(END);
  return store;
}
```

Comment: There is not enough information to help you, can you show the file where you are creating your store?

Comment: @QoP I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

combineReducers creates a new object with the reducers you pass to it, that's the reason you got your states nested.

To fix it export the reducer without using combineReducers since you are not combining any reducers.

```
function helps(state = {
  isFetching: false,
  items: []
}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.HELPS_FEED_REQUEST:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: true
      });
    case types.HELPS_FEED_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        items: [
          ...state.items,
          ...action.items
        ]
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default helps;
```

Scenario with multiple combineReducers.

rootReducer.js

```
import auth from './auth'
import trainer from './trainer/trainerReducer'
import athlete from './athlete/athleteReducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    auth,
    trainer,
    athlete
});
```

trainerReducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import manageAthletes from './manageAthletes'
import manageRoutines from './manageRoutines'

const trainerReducer = combineReducers({
    manageRoutines,
    manageAthletes
});

export default trainerReducer;
```

athleteReducer

```
import trainer from './trainer'
import routine from './routine'

const athleteReducer = combineReducers({
    trainer,
    routine
});

export default athleteReducer;
```

Comment: that makes sense. but the combineReducers should only applied once? I saw an example here: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/shopping-cart/reducers/ 
it has more than one combineReducers(). Why not using only one combineReducers in index.js?

Comment: You can apply it as many times as you want, it's used to make your states more "independent" as you can see in the example I added to the answer :-P.